# Has the Global South been influential in the old churches they derive their existence from?

Tags: ecclesiology, global-christianity, theology

It is said that there are more Anglicans attending Sunday morning services in Nigeria alone than in all the United Kingdom.  Recently the archbishop of Lagos has effectively excommunicated the archbishop of Canterbury for gross heresy; other communions such as Baptists, Methodists and even Roman Catholics have been seeing similar patterns in different stages.  Philip Jenkins thinks this is but the beginning of a new cycle according to a pattern that repeats itself again and again since the early days of the church.  The question is, while we have influential examples in Global South bishops and preachers, how influential are them in the Old World and North America?

Comment: This question will result in the expression of a variety of opinions. It would be far better (in my own view) to ask a specific question of a specific gathering in a specific location. And then go on from that to other specific questions.

Comment: Is the expression of a variety of opinions bad?  How being more specific be better if what I want is a general information?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide statistical evidence to support the claims you make, for example, that there are more Anglicans attending Sunday morning services in Nigeria alone than in all the United Kingdom.   Or at least give us the source from where you got this information.  I fear your question will generate opinions rather than facts.

Comment: *Is the expression of a variety of opinions bad?* Not by itself, but for the format constraints of the SE network of sites, it doesn't fit the scope nor intent of this particular internet resource.   Please head over to the Meta for this Stack and read up on [how we are different](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1808/24204).